# How to give ripple effect above Src image in FAB

Tags: java, android, android-studio, floating-action-button, ripple-effect

I am working with FAB in android and I have increased the Src image size to cover the FAB but now whenever I click on FAB the ripple effect is shown behind the image instead of above it, which doesn't give a feel that FAB is clicked

[image]

My FAB code

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:maxImageSize="@dimen/_130sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_radial_gradient"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:tint="@null"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `foreground` for your `View` to achieve clickable effect:
It should be like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:maxImageSize="@dimen/_130sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_radial_gradient"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"
    app:tint="@null"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
/>
```

We just have to add this line to the `View` to show ripple effect when it is clicked.

> android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

Comment: any solutions for 
Attribute android:foreground has no effect on API levels lower than 23 (current min is 21)?

Answer (score 1):

try add this line to your XML

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
```